# android socket not receiving

Tags: android, sockets

I have a simple client that I'm testing from my android device, I'm testing against a telnet server call telehack.com. The problem is when I request a certain option from the list of menu items the data is sent but not recieved.
Option is **advent** (colossal adventure). I have tried various implementions (socket, socketchannel and select) and still get the same problem after I send advent no data is received, other options from the menu work ok. Even worse is that I have downloaded various telnet clients from the playstore they seem to have the same problem. (Apart from Mobile Telnet which seems to use c++ NDK socket library).

Also looking and Wireshare and telnet client on windows reveals nothing out of the ordinary with the data being sent back.

```
 public void run() {
   mRun = true;

    try {
        Socket sc = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
        inBuffer = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
        outBuffer = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        if (mConnectionListener != null)
            mConnectionListener.connectionStatusChanged(true);

        sc.setSoTimeout(5*60*1000);                    //Socket timeout = 4 minutes

        sc.setTcpNoDelay(true);
        sc.setKeepAlive(true);

        try {


            while (mRun) {


                int size = inBuffer.available();
                if (size > 0)
                {


                    byte[] readBuf = new byte[size];
                    inBuffer.read(readBuf);
```

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about your question and include the entire source code of the scope you are talking about (looks like it's incomplete).

Comment: You might try running this on the Android emulator and packet sniffing on the host, or via a device on a wifi router which can sniff, or via wifi sharing of your dev machine's ethernet connection sniffed there.

Answer (score 0):

The available() method may get you the desired result but it doesn't have to. Some streams just return 0. Use a constant size read buffer instead:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

int bytesRead = 0;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0){
  // note that only the bytes 0 to bytesRead-1 are valid in buffer
}
```